# Problems with method return values in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question about the return value:

dart version:

Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable) (Tue Dec 14 13:32:21 2021 +0100) on "macos_x64

problem:

When I have a void method and return a value, the compiler will report an error, which is fine.

[image]

But, when a method received a function with no return value as a parameter, then no error was reported, as follows:

[image]

Why,Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there is no error in your second screenshot, I do. But you might want to consider upgrading your version of Dart to the newest one (2.16.2)

[image]